# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

[image: El Código de la conexión]

[image: Código del Servlent]
[image: Error que tira en la web]

A que otro drivers se hace referencia o bien que no estoy cargando según yo esta cargado todo correcto , ya que si lo hago por una función main esto carga correctamente

Comment: Si usas TomCat es posible que los drivers de conexión debas colocarlos en el directorio `lib` del proyecto. [Mira esta explicación](http://www.myhow2.net/wp/2013/09/tomcat-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql/).

Comment: Si e colocado el conector allí, pero aun tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes agregar la libreria del conector:

Revisa esta respuesta
[Foro. Conector Base de Datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/error-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dda-al-conectarse-a/122148#122148)