# Error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dda" al conectarse a MySql desde Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Quisiera conectarme a una base de datos que tengo localmente. Tengo el servicio levantado, y ya tengo la base creada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se aprecia es localhost , root pass 1234 ,

y tengo 2 tablas usuario y oid ,

tengo la siguiente clase Java para utilizar esta base

```
 private Persistencia() {
        base = BaseDatos.getInstancia();
        base.conectar("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dda", "root", "1234");
    }


 public void conectar(String url,String u,String p){
        try {
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, u, p);
            stmt = conexion.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al conectar:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

El error que tengo es el siguiente:

> Error al conectar: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Bajastes el [JDBC driver para MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), y después lo agregastes al classpath de tu proyecto?

Comment: no ni idea de eso

Comment: Necesitas hacer eso. Sigue el link que te dejé en mi primer comentario, y baja el conector para tu sistema operativo. Luego agrega el .jar a tu proyecto en Netbeans para que esté en el classpath. Luego vuelva a intentar.

Comment: lo bichare muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrego esta respuesta, porque en realidad la respuesta aceptada es incorrecta.

Cuando uno recibe el error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:...

...esto quiere decir que el código JDBC es incapaz de encontrar el driver necesario para establecer la conexión a la base de datos MySQL.

Con las versiones modernas de Java, existe una sola explicación para este error: **que el conector .jar de MySQL no está en el classpath de la aplicación.**

En este caso, la solución es de simplemente ir a bajar el conector .jar [del sitio de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) y agregarlo al classpath de la aplicación.

---

**¿Ayuda agregar una llamada a `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`?**

No, no cambia nada.

En versiones mucho mas antiguas de Java/JDBC, el error también podía suceder aunque el .jar estuviera en el classpath. Y en estos casos, en efecto se recomendaba de usar `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` para asegurarse de que la clase `Driver` estuviera cargada antes de tratar de establecer la conexión.

Pero a partir de Java 6/JDBC 4.0 (¡hace mas de 10 años ya!) se incluyeron cambios para que ya no fuera necesario llamar a `Class.forName`. Nota lo que la [documentación de `DriverManager` para Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) dice (y claro, la documentación dice lo mismo para las versiones posteriores de Java):

> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()`.

Traducción libre:

> Aplicaciones ya no necesitan cargar los JDBC drivers explicítamente usando `Class.forName()`.

Siendo que este ajuste se hizo hace más de 10 años ya, sería bueno que no siguieramos difundiendo esta idea obsoleta de que se debe llamar `Class.forName` en estas situaciones.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia pero como agrego mi .jar al classpath ?

Comment: La respuesta de AndyC describe como hacerlo con Netbeans.

Comment: cuando termine de escribir el comentario vi que me estaba explicando , mala mia !

Answer (score 1):

Has intentado cargar el Driver `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

```
public Connection conexion() {
    if (conexion == null) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+bd, usuario, contrasena);
            System.out.println("exito");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conexionBD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("error");
        }

    }
    return conexion;
}
```

Comment: tan solo copio . y pego esto y ya estaria ? lo probare !

Comment: es lo mismo que tengo arriba amigo jaja

Comment: en el código que tienes no usas ` Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`

Comment: Por cierto di por hecho que ya tenias descargado el conector de mysql, pero como te dijeron arriba, debes descargarlo y agregarlo a la biblioteca de tu proyecto

Comment: En realidad, hace años ya que agregar la llamada a `Class.forName` ya no se necesita. Eso es una vieja recomendación obsoleta. El problema era únicamente que OP no tenía el conector en su classpath.

Comment: Excelente aporte voy

Comment: lo ideal es trabajar por contexto porque cargar el Driver consume mucho recurso y hay que liberarlos. Mientras que con el pool de conexiones es mas eficiente. Pero para mas eficiencia pueden utilizar Hibernate 5 con JPA2

Comment: Usen tambien wildfly 10

Answer (score 1):

1. Inicialmente debes bajar el conector java para la base de datos especifica y agregar la libreria a tu proyecto.

> Click derecho sobre tu proyecto, luego seleccionas **Propiedades** y en las *Categorias* seleccionas **Librerias** y a tu derecha das click sobre **Agregar Libreria**, finalmente seleccionas la ruta de donde se encuentra guardado tu conector descargado.

2. luego te puedes conectar a la base de datos cargando el driver y generando una conexion para luego enviar la sentencia SQL.

   public Connection getConexion(){

   ```
   Connection conexion = null;
       try {
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
               if(this.getDireccion().equalsIgnoreCase("localhost")){//se conecta en modo local
                   url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost"; //personal
                   conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","clave");
               }else{//se conecta en modo remoto
                   url="jdbc:mysql://"+this.getDireccion(); 
                   conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"usuarioRemoto","clave");
               }
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                       new JFrame(),e.getLocalizedMessage()+
                       "Base de Datos no encontrada",
                       "ADVERTENCIA",
                       JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
               System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage()+"Base de Datos no encontrada");
   ```

   }

   ```
   return conexion;
   ```

   }

Comment: muchas gracias , me ah sido de utilidad