# Error al ejecutar una sentencia preparada

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Tengo un error al ejecutar un método que me devuelve el resultado de una consulta.
El error que me da es el siguiente:

> 'Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet jsp    threw exception   java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream$LoggingPrintStream.println(Logg
>   ingOutputStream.java:228)     at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.threadio.ThreadPrintStream.println(ThreadPrintStr
>   eam.java:205)     at
>   DAOSIMP.DaoPersonaImp.consultarCantidadAspirantes(DaoPersonaImp.java:833)'

Ya revise la conexión y parece estar todo bien.
Adjunto la conexión:

```
                package Conexion;
                import java.sql.*;

                public class Conexion {  
                    protected Connection conexion;
                    protected final String URL_DB= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/nombre_base_de_datos";
                    protected final String JDBC_DRIVER ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                    protected final String CONSTRASENA_DB="contrasena";
                    protected final String USUARIO_DB="usuario_BD";

                    public Conexion() {
                    }
                    public Connection conexion(){
                        return this.conexion;
                    }
                    public void conectar(){

                        try{
                            conexion= DriverManager.getConnection(URL_DB, USUARIO_DB,CONSTRASENA_DB); 
                            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
                        }catch (SQLException e){

                            e.getMessage();
                        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                            System.out.println("Mensaje de error de base de datos" + e.getMessage());

                        }
                    }

                    public void desconectar(){
                        try{
                            if(conexion!=null){
                                if(conexion.isClosed()){
                                    conexion.close();
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(SQLException e){
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Adjunto la clase que extiende de la conexión y el método en el que ejecuto la consulta:

```
                package DAOSIMP;

                import Clases.Persona;
                import Conexion.Conexion;
                import DAOS.DaoPersona;
                import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
                import java.sql.ResultSet;
                import java.sql.SQLException;
                import java.util.ArrayList;

                public class DaoPersonaImp extends Conexion implements DaoPersona{

                    @Override
                    public long consultarCantidadAspirantes() {
                        ResultSet rs;
                        long cantidad=0;
                        try {
                            this.conectar();
                            String sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persona WHERE tipo_persona='A';";

                            PreparedStatement stm=this.conexion.prepareStatement(sql);//Esta es la linea 833 que dice el error
                            rs = stm.executeQuery();
                            while(rs.next()){
                                cantidad=rs.getLong(1);
                            }
                            return cantidad;
                        }catch(SQLException e){
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            return 0;
                        }finally{
                            this.desconectar();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Y simplemente estoy llamando al método así:

```
                DaoPersona daoPersona=new DaoPersonaImp();
                long cantidadAspirantes=daoPersona.consultarCantidadAspirantes();
```

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta: [Conexión base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/error-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dda-al-conectarse-a/122148#122148)

Comment: @Jonathan: Los detalles de tu error no corresponden con el código que pusistes. En particular no veo nada que corresponda a `org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.threadio.ThreadPrintStream.println` en tu método `consultarCantidadAspirantes()`. ¿Hay algo especial es cuento a tu aplicación que no podemos observar con el código que has incluído? ¿Sabes qué es `org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.threadio.ThreadPrintStream.println`?

Comment: Cuando te tira ése error, es arrancándolo desde un servidor? hay algún scriplet con variables java en algún archivo JSP asociado que pueda estar trayendote algo null?, si es así, usá arrancarlo por Main. Poné todos los parámetros harcodeados y dale arranque a ver que pasa. Si anda, o te cambia el tipo de error te paso una respuesta.

Comment: Ya solucioné el error, lo primero que hice fue poner el Class.forName antes:
`
try{
       Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
       conexion= DriverManager.getConnection(URL_DB, 
                        USUARIO_DB,CONSTRASENA_DB); 
                           
                        }
`
Después volví a crea el usuario con el que estaba accediendo a la base de datos, no sé porqué, pero al parecer no se estaba autenticando, por ende la conexión me devolvía null al no haberse conectado con éxito.