# Error al ejecutar mi código - No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysqlconnector

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Encuentro el mensaje de error

> No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/escueladigital

Ayuda por favor!

Todo al parecer esta bien, pero me sigue saliendo error cuando la url esta bien o eso creo.

Comment: Vas a tener que dar más información, sobretodo en relación a las librerías del proyecto.

Comment: Tendrás que añadir el driver de jdbc mysql a tu proyecto. A parte como comenta @pablo deberías añadir más información.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dda" al conectarse a MySql desde Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/error-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dda-al-conectarse-a)

Comment: no se logra ver la imagen que subi ? :(

Comment: Por lo que veo te falta esta linea `Class.forName("com.mysql. jdbc.Driver"); ` al principio, que registra el driver de conexión para la base de datos

Comment: pero para el mysql-connector-java-8.0.12 se sigue utilizando el Class.forName ?

Comment: Ahí ya me has pillado. Investiga y prueba. :)

Comment: @DiegoLoL El cargar los drivers a mano (`Class.forName`) hace **MUCHO TIEMPO** que no es necesario. Aunque aún puede pasar que alguien esté modificando un proyecto antiguo o siguiendo un tutorial desfasado, opino que sugerir esta técnica "a tontas y a locas" (sin verificar que pueda ser pertinente) confunde más que ayuda (en este caso se usa JDK 8 y la versión 8 del driver MySQL). Ah! Y la clase del driver cambió en la última versión del jar...

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76 por la información. Pues me tocará a mi investigar y mirar bien la documentación. :)

Comment: Ya lo solucione , de igual manera gracias a todos . !

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar la linea seguiente

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql. jdbc.Driver");
```

y tu problema se solucionara.