# Error al intentar ejecutar *.jar

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jar

Estoy ejecutando como administrador un archivo *.jar desde un archivo *.bat el cual se ejecuta correctamente pero cuando llama al *.jar genera un error de base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer no encuentra el JDBC de MySql, sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto en el Netbeans funciona perfectamente esta es mi clase conexión

```
public class Conexion {

   public java.sql.Connection con = null;
   private String host, username;
   private String database = "";
   private String password = "";
   private String port = "";
   private String classname = "";
   private String url;

   public Conexion() {
       try {
           properties();

           Class.forName(classname);
           DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
           con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

   }

   public final void properties() throws
           IOException,
           ClassNotFoundException {
       Properties prop = new Properties();
       try {
         prop.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/properties/datasource.properties"));  
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Controlador.conexion.properties()"+ e );
       }
       classname = prop.getProperty("driver");
       host = prop.getProperty("host");
       port = prop.getProperty("port");
       database = prop.getProperty("database");
       username = prop.getProperty("username");
       password = prop.getProperty("password");
       url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database;

   }

   public void cerrar() throws SQLException {
       con.close();
   }

}
```

Comprobé que leyera el archivo properties y funciona correcto, este es el empaquetado en Netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has intentado instalar el jar del conector de mysql? https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html , probablemente en tu proyecto tienes en tus dependencias el jar instalado en .m2 pero no en el sistema donde lo ejecutas de manera global.

Comment: En el bat en en el que llamas a tu jar, ¿estás incluyendo en el classpath el jar de mysql que usas? Netbeans se encarga de hacerlo si lo ejecutas desde Netbeans, pero si te haces un bat tuyo, tienes que incluir en el classpath todos los jar a los que haces referencia en tu aplicación.

Comment: No, tengo agregado ningún classpath, solo tengo la ruta de donde esta el *.Jar como podría agregar el classpath?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dda" al conectarse a MySql desde Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/error-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dda-al-conectarse-a)

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione lo único que hice fue abrir el .jar con winrar cree la carpeta lib le agregue en esta carpeta el driver y luego modifique el MANIFEST.MF agregándole la linea Class-Path: ./lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar y funciono perfento