# Como solucionar java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación WEB, pero me aparece el siguiente problema:

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=Prueba;user=sa;password=admin;

Mi clase conexion es la siguiente:

```
    private static Connection con = null;

public static Connection Conectar() {

    try {
        String urlConexion = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                + "database=Prueba;"
                + "user=sa;"
                + "password=admin;";

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlConexion);

        return con;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Tengo agregado el conector a la libreria de mi aplicativo y sigue mostrando eso.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que la BD realmente está corriendo en el puerto `1433`?

Comment: Si, ya intente desde un aplicativo java swing, ingresar datos desde un CRUD y funciona correctamente la conexion. Probe desde el cmd para ver lo de puerto y si esta corriendo.

Comment: Si la BD está OK entonces puede que no hayas instalado el JDBC correcto o que no lo hayas puesto en el sitio correcto.

Comment: Para probar si JDBC está bien instalado y en contexto puedes hacer esto: `try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    System.out.println("Driver OK");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}`

Comment: Revisa aquí [todos los tipos de controladores JDBC que existen para SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/system-requirements-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) y compara si tienes instalado el JDBC adecuado. Ahí explica los requisitos según tu entorno, versión de BD, etc.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dda" al conectarse a MySql desde Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/error-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dda-al-conectarse-a)

Answer (score 0):

Si ya comprobaste la conexión e incluso verificaste que se usa el puerto 1433 como comentas, entonces la instalación del Driver tal vez no es correcta.

[Descarga](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) y agrega el .jar dentro del directorio `Libraries` de tu proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No esta de más revisar que SQL Server puede permitir conexiones remotas, revisa el Configuration Manager de SQL Server, habilita TPC/IP y asegura que usas el puerto 1433.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como comenta A. Cedano puedes revisar que la conexión desde tu aplicación es correcta, mediante:

```
try { 
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");     
       System.out.println("Driver funciona correctamente."); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage()); 
}
```

Revisa este excelente tutorial:

[**Conectar SQL Server con Java**](http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2013/06/conectar-sql-server-con-java.html)

---

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html

Uso de la autenticación de Windows con una conexión JDBC
El controlador JDBC no admite la autenticación de Windows si dicho controlador se utiliza en sistemas operativos que no son de Windows. Las credenciales de autenticación de Windows, como el nombre de usuario y la contraseña, al conectarse a SQL Server desde sistemas operativos que no son de Windows. En estos casos, las aplicaciones deben utilizar la autenticación de SQL Server.

En la cadena de conexión de JDBC, debe especificarse el parámetro integratedSecurity para conectarse mediante la autenticación de Windows. El controlador JDBC admite la autenticación de Windows integrada para los sistemas operativos de Windows a través del parámetro de cadena de conexión integratedSecurity.

Para usar la autenticación integrada

Instale el controlador JDBC.

Copie el archivo sqljdbc_auth.dll en un directorio de la ruta de sistema de Windows en el equipo donde está instalado el controlador JDBC.

Los archivos `sqljdbc_auth.dll` se instalan en la ubicación siguiente:

```
<directorio de instalación>\sqljdbc_<versión>\<idioma>\auth\
```

Comment: Leyendo el enlace, quede con una duda; cual es mi directorio raíz del proyecto es este [src/conf ]

Comment: Revisa la actualizaciòn, la ruta serìa:<directorio de instalación>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\auth\

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en la cadena de conexión no es `database` sino que es `databaseName` corrigiendo tu problema el código quedaria asi

```
private static Connection con = null;

public static Connection Conectar() {

    try {
        String urlConexion = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
            + "databaseName=Prueba;"
            + "user=sa;"
            + "password=admin;";

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlConexion);

        return con;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        return null;
    }

}
```