# MySQLConnector Library could not be found Java Netbeans MacOS

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector, mysqlconnector.jar

El problema que tengo es que mude mi proyecto a MacOS, y a la hora de hacer pruebas ejecutar el programa que estoy creando, me da el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "this.con" is null
```

Y creo que viene por aqui el problema, es que **me falta el MySQLConnector**, aqui en mi sistema operativo ***instale MySQL 8.0.30*** y el proyecto estaba en MySQL 8.0.29 y el connector lo habia cargado mediante un JAR que en este caso veo que no me esta sirviendo en mac porque no me quita la falla.

Estuve buscando el .JAR para importarlo en la libreria pero no he podido encontrar para macOS, pido disculpas pero quizas posiblemente me este equivocando en algo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el jar no depende del OS. Esa es la gracia de usar Java, la JVM se encarga de la plataforma. Descarga EL jar y añádelo al proyecto

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dda" al conectarse a MySql desde Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/error-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dda-al-conectarse-a)

Comment: Cree la libreria MySQLConnector y agregue el jar dentro de ella, y me sigue dando error.
Problem: The project uses a class library called "MySQLConnector", but this class library was not found.
Solution: Click Resolve to open the Library Manager and create a new class library called "MySQLConnector".

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado gracias a @Alfarobravo y @Ruslan López
Cree una libreria llamada MySQLConnector y dentro de ella subi los .jar[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]