# Cannot invoke java.sql.Connection.createStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection, mysqlconnector.jar

tengo el siguiente problema. Importe el .jar mysql-connector-java-8.0.30 al proyecto cree la libreria con el nombre MySQLConnector y al ejecutar el programa me da el error que es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "this.con" is null
at kioscov1.PanelAdministrativo.actualizarTabla(PanelAdministrativo.java:80)
at kioscov1.PanelAdministrativo.<init>(PanelAdministrativo.java:38)
```

El codigo en cuestion lo tengo asi:

```
    Connection con;

public void conexionDb() {
    try {
        var url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/" + host.getText() + ":" + port.getText() + "/" + dbName.getText() + "?useSSL=false&useTimezone=GMT%2D3&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user.getText(), passdb.getText());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
```

Y el error de la linea 80 que me marca es el siguiente:
Seria: **Statement ejecuto = con.createStatement();**

```
    void actualizarTabla() {
    try {
        conexionDb();
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablaResultados.getModel();
        modelo.setRowCount(0);
        Statement ejecuto = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = ejecuto.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nombre LIKE '%" + buscador.getText() + "%'");
        while (rs.next()) {//se valida si hay resultados
            do {
                String[] fila = {rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8)};
                modelo.addRow(fila);
            } while (rs.next());
            {
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        msgLog.requestFocus();
    } finally {
    }
}
```

El error es generado por el .jar? o hay algo que esto olvidando en el codigo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dda" al conectarse a MySql desde Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/error-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dda-al-conectarse-a)

Comment: Hola, no ya que no es el mismo error, mi error esta en la descripcion.

Comment: Hola.
El error es claro. con es null en ese punto. No puedes llamar al método createStatement() de una variable que es null y no tiene dentro una Connection. Asegurate de asignarle valor antes
¿Esto ha sacado algún error System.out.print(e);?

Comment: Hola Chuidiang, aunque lo deje  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user.getText(),passdb.getText()); me sigue dando error.