# Error al ejecutar código Java: Error en la bd: 0-No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://172.23.0.2:3306/appjava

Tags: java, mysql, vscode

es mi primera vez posteando en este sitio que tanto me ha ayudado en el pasado. Estoy intentando hacer un código con Visual Studio Code con el cual poder afectar una base de datos, pero me está dando error en la propia conexión. La ip que utilizo para Workbench es 172.23.0.2. ¿Alguien tiene idea de qué puede estar pasando?

El código en cuestión

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class registro {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            // Conectamos con la base de datos
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://172.23.0.2:3306/appjava", "root", "admini");
            // Creamos un objeto para enviar sentencias SQL a la BD
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            // Ejecutamos la consulta SQL
            System.out.println("* Elige una de las siguientes opciones (1-4)");
            System.out.println("1. Registrar Usuario");
            System.out.println("2. Modificar Usuario");
            System.out.println("3. Acceder Usuario");
            System.out.println("4. Salir");
            int opcion = sc.nextInt();

            while(opcion !=4){
                switch (opcion){
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Nombre de usuario: ");
                        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Contraseña: ");
                        String contraseña = sc.nextLine();
                        int rownewuser = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO appjava.infouser (usuario, contraseña) VALUES ('"+nombre+"','"+contraseña+"')");
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Nombre de usuario: ");
                        String nomMod = sc.nextLine();
                        sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Contraseña: ");
                        String passMod = sc.nextLine();
                        ResultSet rsmod = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM infouser WHERE nombre= "+nomMod);
                        if (rsmod == null){
                            System.out.println("No existe");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Nuevo nombre: ");
                            String nombrenuevo = sc.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Nueva contraseña: ");
                            String contranueva = sc.nextLine();
                            int rowmoduser = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE infouser SET usuario=" + nombrenuevo+", contraseña="+contranueva+"WHERE usuario="+nomMod+"");
                        }
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Nombre de usuario: ");
                        String nomLogin = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Contraseña: ");
                        String passLogin = sc.nextLine();
                        ResultSet rslog = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM infouser WHERE nombre= '"+nomLogin+"'AND contraseña='"+passLogin+"'");
                        if (rslog == null){
                            System.out.println("No existe");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Acceso a la BD");
                        }
                    case 4:
                        break;
                }
            }


            
        }   catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en la bd: " + e.getErrorCode() + "-" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, estaré eternamente agradecido. Buenas tardes.
Como dije anteriormente, estoy usando Visual Studio Code, e intentando conectar con una Base de Datos MYSQL.

Comment: Ya tienes el driver de Mysql descargado y en el classpath?

Comment: Era eso y poner unas librerias jar en una carpeta lib. Todo bien!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dda" al conectarse a MySql desde Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/error-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dda-al-conectarse-a)

Answer (score 0):

lo mas probable es que te falta el controlador JDBC MySQL  y esto lo puedes encontrar en el  sitio web oficial de MySQL:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
```

Una vez que hayas descargado el controlador, debes agregar el archivo `jar` a tu proyecto
Si estás usando `NetBeans` o `IntelliJ IDEA`, puedes agregar el archivo `jar` a tu proyecto haciendo clic derecho en el proyecto y seleccionando `Propiedades` o `Build Path`, dependiendo del IDE que estés utilizando.

Luego, en la pestaña `Libraries` o `Classpath`, haz clic en `Add JAR` o `Add External JAR`, busca el archivo jar del controlador JDBC MySQL que descargaste anteriormente y selecciónalo para agregarlo a tu proyecto. y con eso ya estaria funcionando segun yo